# iPhone Enterprise (in-house) v.s. App Store Distribution

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution, enterprise

Is this statement correct?  Seems strange to me...

From Apple FAQ:

---

If I am enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program, can I distribute my apps on the App Store?

The ability to distribute apps on the App Store is only available to developers enrolled in the standard iOS Developer Program. The iOS Developer Enterprise Program only allows you to distribute your apps to employees or members of your organization through Ad Hoc distribution.

---

So then how can a company to both?  Enterprise and App Store?

Comment: Why closed, this is a direct question on how to deploy apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign up for both programs.  Luckily, the other one is only $99.

Comment: So then this will require a different apple id for the 2nd program.  Just tried to "add" an Enterprise program to a Developer program and it would not allow it.

Comment: Yes, but that may not altogether be a bad thing.  There are reasons why you would want to make them separate, including the app signature and what account the "team agent," the only person who can actually upload to the store is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distribute both enterprise and App Store you will need two iOS developer programs